# What happens when you target an active BKB user with Omnislash?

Tags: dota-2

1. What happens if the defender BKB's first and then becomes the target of Omnislash?
2. What happens if the defender BKB's after already being targeted by Omnislash?

---

Example:
https://www.twitch.tv/videos/166432856?t=8h34m37s

Answer (score 5):

Omnislash completely ignores spell immunity and deals physical damage, so a Black King Bar would have no effect at all.